# Ext JS | Download chart with additional data

Tags: extjs, extjs7, extreact

Is it possible to download chart with additional data?
For example add labels when chart.download() method is called, I want these labels to be visible on download result (.png image), but not in rendered view.

I have label described in chart component, with property: hidden:true.

I've dived deep in [Ext.draw.Container](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/src/Container.js-2.html#Ext.draw.Container-method-download) source code, but still have no clue about how to resolve the mentioned case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will have to render two charts: Visible and "Invisible". In the following example I have two charts, the first one is visible, the second one is located below (You cannot see it because the scrolling is off). On clicking the Prevoew or Download button the "invisible" chart's .preview() and .download() methods are called.

[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/37re)

P.S.
Code is not clean, it is just the proof of concept.